# jQuery function calling ajax not working/returning anything

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am writing an app (not web app) for mobile devices using icenium which uses javascript etc rather than its native language.

The app displays rows from a data base, displaying events. The user then clicks on an event which displays more information on the event, however I am having trouble calling the ajax from a js function as below:

```
function showSingle(itemId){

            //document.write(itemId);
            $('#output').fadeOut();
            $('#single').fadeIn("fast");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://dev.123456789.co.uk/getSingle.php',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: { dbId: itemId },
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, status){

                        var linkedPageSingle = '<h2>'+item.eventName+'</h2>'
                            + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

                        $('#single').append(linkedPageSingle);
                        // pageId = $('#pageid').html();
                        $('#single').text('debugdebug.');
                },
                error: function(){
                    $('#single').text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
        });
      }
```

This does not return any data, it doesn't even return $('#single').text('debugdebug.'); so there must be a problem with the ajax call? Also

```
error: function(){
                    $('#single').text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
```

Is not outputted. Can you spot an error in this? The call to the function is here:

```
var linkedPage = '<h2><a href="#" onClick="showSingle('+item.id+')">'+item.eventName+'</a></h2>'
                            + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';
```

Which is in a document.ready section of the page, inside an ajax method (which works).

getSingle.php:

```
<?php

/*
    * Script to connect to database and pull out information for app!
*/

include 'connect.php';

$dbId = $_POST['dbId'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calTest where `id`='$dbId'");
$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

?>
```

Can't see where I have gone wrong, Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your js console?

Comment: Did you checked your console ? what error it is displaying ?

Comment: Can you give me valid itemId value

Comment: I can't access a console as far as I am aware as its in the iPhone app. a valid itemId would look like showSingle(2)

Comment: Change <a href="#" onclick="showSingle(item.id)"></a>

Comment: Where is the `jsoncallback` function ?

Comment: Sorry @UmairIqbal the whole line calling it is this: (editing OP) var linkedPage = '<h2><a href="#" onClick="showSingle('+item.id+')">'+item.eventName+'</a></h2>'
                            + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

Comment: @Codesen a valid id would be 2

Comment: 2 returns empty value from DB. check the query with DB

Comment: When you click on the link are you sure the showSingle function is called? if yes just alert item.id in it whether it goes or not

Comment: @UmairIqbal good suggestion, forgot to do that, yes, it does alert the correct id inside the function

Comment: Can you please post your getSingle.ph as well ?

Comment: @UmairIqbal It is at the bottom of my op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with Posting of data

```
$dbId = $_POST['dbId'];

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'];
```

you are using the get or post method together

Answer (score 1):

You set the callback to `jsoncallback` so you need to add that function to parse item:

```
function showSingle(itemId){

        //document.write(itemId);
        //$('#output').fadeOut();
        //$('#single').fadeIn("fast");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://dev.thedesignworks.co.uk/getSingle.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { dbId: itemId },
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000
        });
}

function jsoncallback(data, status) {
    var linkedPageSingle;
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         linkedPageSingle = '<h2>'+item.eventName+'</h2>'
                        + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                        + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

         $('#single').append(linkedPageSingle);
         // pageId = $('#pageid').html();
    });​
    $('#single').text('debugdebug.');
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I thought jsoncallback would be valid because it is in the getSingle.php: echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

Comment: when you assign `jsoncallback` to `jsonp` you automatically tell AJAX to pass the response to that javascript function, not PHP.

Comment: Ah progress! When it's on that I am now getting "There was an error loading the data." I have changed the function name to jsoncallbackSingle as it was conflicting with another jsoncallback.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! If I could give 2 correct answers I would, i'm sure somewhere in here it has helped it work however it was changing the post to get that made it work in the end, upvoted however and learned good practice from you, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function showSingle(itemId){

            //document.write(itemId);
            $('#output').fadeOut();
            $('#single').fadeIn("fast");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://dev.thedesignworks.co.uk/getSingle.php',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: { dbId: itemId },
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data, status){
                        alert(data)
if (data.length > 0) {
                        var linkedPageSingle = '<h2>'+item.eventName+'</h2>'
                            + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

                        $('#single').append(linkedPageSingle);
                        // pageId = $('#pageid').html();
                        $('#single').text('debugdebug.');
}
                },
                error: function(){
                    $('#single').text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
        });
      }
```

The php page will be

```
    <?php

    /*
        * Script to connect to database and pull out information for app!
    */

    include 'connect.php';

    $dbId = $_POST['dbId'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calTest where `id`='$dbId'");
    $records = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }

if (count($records) > 0)
    echo json_encode($records);


    ?>
```